# condtional split SSIS where both data sources have Nulls

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am using ssis 2010

I have a conditional split

Source A Column ID - An Excel sheet

Source B column ID (1)- A table of Customers

I only want to add data to a table from the excel source, if the ID does not exist in the table

ID contains a combination of letters and numbers

normally this would work

```
!ISNULL(ID) && ISNULL([ID (1)])
```

but there can be instances now, where both the Excel Source and The Data Table can have nulls for the ID column

How do I amend the above to cater for nulls please. I have tried other code, but I get the Conditional split error about Boolean data

Answer (score 1):

The typical model looks like this:

source Excel  ==> Lookup (check if ID exists in table redirect no match) ==> Load NoMatch

I am unsure what you are trying to do with nulls in ID columns???

Comment: ignore them for now, just want to add new IDs to the data source table, that are newly found in the excel document please

Comment: this solution does exactly what you want to do

Comment: I am not very fay with lookup as used previously conditional split @KeithL